# React Symfony assets Blocked loading mixed active content

Tags: reactjs, symfony

I have been searching for a solution for this issue but obviously I have not found one, since I am posting this question. I know that I have done this before, so I do not understand how I made it work, but I am receiving the following message of blocked loading mixed active content, yet the React files are located on the same server and the same domain as the Symfony files are located

[image: Blocked loading mixed active content screen shot]

My Symfony base.html.twig file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome! Tarik{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
        {% include 'react-symfony-templates/index.html.twig' %}
    </body>
</html>
```

My index.html.twig file:

```
<script src="{{ asset('build/layout.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('build/rep_log_react.js') }}"></script>
```

I am just starting the project, so that is all that I have, but without the layout.js and rep_log_react.js files loading, then there are no react files for the symfony project to load.

I have also tried to surround the script tags within the index.html.twig:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('build/layout.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('build/rep_log_react.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Still the same error. Once again, I know that I have done this before, and I am sure that I am missing something small, like do not use symfony serve or something, but I need some fresh eyes to view this.

As usual, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am editing my answer because this is not a permanent solution. It turns out that if I shutdown the encore dev-server and the symfony server, then all of the links return to http. How can I configure this to point to https://localhost:8080/build

**Second edit**

**Here is the solution - when running the encore dev-server use the following flags**

```
sudo yarn encore dev-server --port 8080 --https --hot
```

**This should be followed by adding the security exemptions to your browser**

Basically the following command line is all that is needed, but I ran into a few errors that I had to fix. First, the command line that allows for encore to run the build directory on localhost:8080/build

```
yarn encore dev-server --hot
```

When I ran the aforementioned command, I received an error that manifest.json was missing, which lead to the series of commands. Since I am on a mac, I had to use sudo at the beginning of each command

```
sudo yarn add --dev @symfony/webpack-encore
sudo yarn add webpack-notifier --dev
sudo yarn encore dev
```

This was followed by altering the following files to reflect "https" instead of "http"
/public/build/manifest.json - I shutdown both servers before changing the following files.

I use vi with the following command to search and replace:

```
%s/http:/https:/g

{
"build/admin.js": "https://localhost:8080/build/admin.js",
"build/app.css": "https://localhost:8080/build/app.css",
"build/app.js": "https://localhost:8080/build/app.js",
"build/layout.js": "https://localhost:8080/build/layout.js",
"build/runtime.js": "https://localhost:8080/build/runtime.js",
"build/vendors~admin.js": "https://localhost:8080/build/vendors~admin.js",
"build/vendors~admin~app~layout.js": "https://localhost:8080/build/vendors~admin~app~layout.js",
"build/vendors~admin~layout.js": "https://localhost:8080/build/vendors~admin~layout.js",
"build/vendors~app.js": "https://localhost:8080/build/vendors~app.js",
"build/vendors~layout.js": "https://localhost:8080/build/vendors~layout.js"
}
```

/public/build/entrypoints.json

```
"entrypoints": {
  "layout": {
    "js": [
      "https://localhost:8080/build/runtime.js",
      "https://localhost:8080/build/vendors~admin~app~layout.js",
      "https://localhost:8080/build/vendors~admin~layout.js",
      "https://localhost:8080/build/vendors~layout.js",
      "https://localhost:8080/build/layout.js"
    ]
  },
  "app": {
    "js": [
      "https://localhost:8080/build/runtime.js",
      "https://localhost:8080/build/vendors~admin~app~layout.js",
      "https://localhost:8080/build/vendors~app.js",
      "https://localhost:8080/build/app.js"
    ],
    "css": [
      "https://localhost:8080/build/app.css"
    ]
  },
  "admin": {
    "js": [
      "https://localhost:8080/build/runtime.js",
      "https://localhost:8080/build/vendors~admin~app~layout.js",
      "https://localhost:8080/build/vendors~admin~layout.js",
      "https://localhost:8080/build/vendors~admin.js",
      "https://localhost:8080/build/admin.js"
    ]
  }
}
}
```

Restart both servers

```
symfony server:start
```

In a separate terminal window

```
yarn encore dev-server --hot
```

[image: The proof is in the pudding - see the following screen shot]